# How to fix this error "Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option"

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to create Kafka topic but I am getting the error.

```
$ docker exec -ti kafka-server1 \
>   /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create \
>   --zookeeper zookeeper-server:2181 \
>   --replication-factor 1 \
>   --partitions 1 \
>   --topic topic_model_local

Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:517)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:47)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error? Please follow official documentation

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your interesting in my question.
I couldn't get the point what you mean.
What does mean by official documentation?

Comment: 1) What is unclear? You can run `kafka-topics.sh` by itself or with `--help`, and it shows all **recognized options**. `zookeeper` is not one. 2) Where did you download Kafka? (You can learn it without Docker, which I would recommend) What documentation/tutorials are you following? What version of Kafka are you using? Kafka has an official website and a getting started guide that (for the version you downloaded) does not use Zookeeper as a CLI option https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the quickstart docs:

```
Option zookeeper is deprecated, use --bootstrap-server instead.
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your helping me.
Could you please give me examples with using bootstrap server?

Comment: @dev-ninja It's `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` for the Docker image